# How do I get HTML or New Line / Carraige Return in Html.ValidationSummary() via C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

This may not be possible without writing some crazy extension method which I do not plan on doing.  I know the `ValidationSummary()` is encoded for security.  **I'm just curious if I'm missing something** obvious...?

I have a simple `<%= Html.ValidationSummary() %>` in my form.  For certain situations, errors are thrown and it would be nice if I could have a little more control over the appearance of the error(s).

For example - when I import a CSV file, I throw the following error to the `ValidationSummary()` if the headers are not in an acceptable format or include special characters:

```
constraintValidatorContext.AddInvalid(invalidHeaders.Count() == 1
                        ? string.Format("The following column header is invalid: {0}.", badHeaders)
                        : string.Format("There were multiple invalid column headers including: {0}.", badHeaders), "General");
```

It would be swell if I could **display the multiple headers in a list as follows**:

```
string.Format("There were multiple invalid column headers including: <li>{0}</li>", badHeaders)
```

This displays the HTML.  **Even if I could just throw in a NewLine here or there, it would be helpful (\n \r)**...  Am I just ignorant of something?

Comment: Well, I ended up writing my own extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newlines have no effect in HTML, you want a `<br />` tag.

You could always roll your own to get more control over the output. Here's the MVC2 source for that helper. It basically looks through the

```
public static MvcHtmlString ValidationSummary(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, bool excludePropertyErrors, string message, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes) {
        if (htmlHelper == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("htmlHelper");
        }

        FormContext formContext = htmlHelper.ViewContext.GetFormContextForClientValidation();
        if (formContext == null && htmlHelper.ViewData.ModelState.IsValid) {
            return null;
        }

        string messageSpan;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(message)) {
            TagBuilder spanTag = new TagBuilder("span");
            spanTag.SetInnerText(message);
            messageSpan = spanTag.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal) + Environment.NewLine;
        }
        else {
            messageSpan = null;
        }

        StringBuilder htmlSummary = new StringBuilder();
        TagBuilder unorderedList = new TagBuilder("ul");

        IEnumerable<ModelState> modelStates = null;
        if (excludePropertyErrors) {
            ModelState ms;
            htmlHelper.ViewData.ModelState.TryGetValue(htmlHelper.ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix, out ms);
            if (ms != null) {
                modelStates = new ModelState[] { ms };
            }
        }
        else {
            modelStates = htmlHelper.ViewData.ModelState.Values;
        }

        if (modelStates != null) {
            foreach (ModelState modelState in modelStates) {
                foreach (ModelError modelError in modelState.Errors) {
                    string errorText = GetUserErrorMessageOrDefault(htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext, modelError, null /* modelState */);
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(errorText)) {
                        TagBuilder listItem = new TagBuilder("li");
                        listItem.SetInnerText(errorText);
                        htmlSummary.AppendLine(listItem.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (htmlSummary.Length == 0) {
            htmlSummary.AppendLine(_hiddenListItem);
        }

        unorderedList.InnerHtml = htmlSummary.ToString();

        TagBuilder divBuilder = new TagBuilder("div");
        divBuilder.MergeAttributes(htmlAttributes);
        divBuilder.AddCssClass((htmlHelper.ViewData.ModelState.IsValid) ? HtmlHelper.ValidationSummaryValidCssClassName : HtmlHelper.ValidationSummaryCssClassName);
        divBuilder.InnerHtml = messageSpan + unorderedList.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);

        if (formContext != null) {
            // client val summaries need an ID
            divBuilder.GenerateId("validationSummary");
            formContext.ValidationSummaryId = divBuilder.Attributes["id"];
            formContext.ReplaceValidationSummary = !excludePropertyErrors;
        }
        return divBuilder.ToMvcHtmlString(TagRenderMode.Normal);
    }
```

ValidationSummaryValidCssClassName is "validation-summary-errors" and ValidationSummaryValidCssClassName is "validation-summary-valid".